# AWS Cloudformation error: Template format error: Invalid outputs property : [Ref]

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use this template:

https://gist.github.com/jbt/712d1abdf40db84ea5e24d8c5d0db712

found here:

https://www.gosquared.com/blog/simple-high-availability-wordpress-hosting-on-aws

But I receive the error in the object:

> Template format error: Invalid outputs property : [Ref].

If I open the designer and try to validate the template in JSON format I received this error.

> Template contains errors.: Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute

I'm quite new in yaml template so I don't know exactly which could be the problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Outputs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) are incorrect.

Instead of:

```
Outputs:
  TargetGroup: !Ref PublicAlbTargetGroup
```

There should be:

```
Outputs:
  TargetGroup: 
    Value: !Ref PublicAlbTargetGroup
```

Please note that the template can have other issues which are not apparent yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin! The errors could be provoked just because is an old template?

Comment: @PonzioPilato `TargetGroup` issue was just incorrect syntax. But if you have other issues, they could be because resources changed over time.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Until now I fixed two errors, regarding the first, a specific SG that obviously I don't have in my account and I correct it with a !Ref, than the AMI provided wasn't anymore in AWS. Now I receive this error: "Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 2". I tried adding <script></script> around UserData, but no success....any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

```
[cfn-lint] E6002: Output TargetGroup is missing property Value
```